# Using blueprint.sass in Webby/Compass Integration

Tags: ruby, sass, blueprint-css, compass-sass, webby

I'm following an article here:

http://gom-jabbar.org/articles/2009/02/04/don-t-use-css-or-table-layout-use-sass-ad-compass

more specifically the section entitled **"Concrete Example of using
Compass and Sass for creating a layout that people generally use
tables for"**

The example references `@import blueprint.sass`

Where is this file located as my webby project does not seem to be able to find it.

(Also note that I'm using Ubuntu)

My **layout.sass** file looks like this (nothing fancy):

```
---
filter: sass
extension: css
layout: nil
---
@import blueprint.sass
body
  +blueprint-typography
```

I get the following error when running **webby**:

```
create  output/stylesheets/layout.css
[22:56:30] ERROR: while rendering page 'content/stylesheets/layout.sass'
[22:56:30] ERROR: sass filter error: "File to import not found or unreadable: blueprint.sass."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright figured it out...

You have to download/install the most recent installation of haml which isn't yet specified on the [compass primer](http://acts-as-architect.blogspot.com/2008/11/compass-primer.html)

**This should actually be the first step in installing it!**

And here is how that step goes:

1. Download the latest version of HAML with the following command: *git clone git://github.com/nex3/haml.git*
   (This will create a new directory *./haml/*)
2. Change to the *./haml/* directory.
3. In the *./haml/* directory type the following command: *rake install*

Comment: Please don't take offense, but you don't read very well. This is and has been the FIRST step in the primer for a very long time.

Screenshot: http://img.skitch.com/20090413-p3qrneq961jtx4qsc655pp32sm.png

Comment: I did git haml, as the first step, but I didn't know that you had to install it like this http://tinyurl.com/d8j7bb.

Comment: Thanks for updating the documentation! 
 I don't come from a Ruby background

Answer (score 1):

Definitely need to upgrade to the latest edge haml. That was a bug in how comments get parsed that was fixed in the last month or so.

```
git checkout git://github.com/nex3/haml.git
cd haml
rake install
```

Comment: Okay I tried it with clone instead of checkout...but all that did was give me a haml directory, and it didn't update the version that I have installed with Ubuntu.  Which appears to be what it is using...got the same error as above.

Comment: Okay now I get an error: [22:56:30] ERROR: while rendering page 'content/stylesheets/layout.sass'
[22:56:30] ERROR: sass filter error: "File to import not found or unreadable: blueprint.sass."

Comment: That error makes me think that sass isn't configured to find the compass libraries. Can you show me how you've configured webby with compass?

Comment: I just followed the directions here:
http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/webby-integration